# Combine WHERE and HAVING clause in a query

Tags: sql-server, where-clause, having-clause

I have the following query

```
SELECT  analysis, start, stop
FROM table     
GROUP BY start    
WHERE userid = 12 AND playerid = 67     
HAVING CAST(start AS date) = MAX(CAST(start AS date))    
ORDER BY start ;
```

start and stop are type datetime, like `2016-10-23 00:00:00.000`

we have a lot of them for the same day. 
I want to have all the start/stop in the same, last day.

So ,my logic is get all the start and stop datetimes of the max day (=today)

So if today is `2016-10-23` get all the start and stop that are

```
`2016-10-23 00:10:00.000`
`2016-10-23 00:20:00.000`
`2016-10-23 00:40:00.000`
`2016-10-23 00:80:00.000`
```

The error I get is `incorrect syntax near the keyword WHERE`

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: WHERE must be before GROUP BY.

Because the WHERE clause is executed on EVERY row, but the HAVING is executed on every group of record

Comment: As Bestter said `WHERE --- GROUP BY -- HAVING`. But also if your `GROUP BY start` Then  `start  = MAX(start)` for all dates. So you probably should  check the condition or the group by

Comment: That being said this still needs a rewrite as `GROUP BY start HAVING CAST(start AS date) = MAX(CAST(start AS date))  ` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to select all rows the date of which is the maximum date in the table. One main query for the rows to show and a subquery in the where clause for the maximum day,

```
select *
from mytable
where cast(start as date) = (select max(cast(start as date)) from mytable);
```

Comment: codebot you didn't say anything on your question. But you may consider add the same condition for `stop`. Because if you start at `23:00` but end at `3:00` then isn't clear if `max(date)` should be today or tomorrow.

Comment: Also is better use `where start  >= (select max(cast(start as date)) from mytable)` that way you can use index over `start` field